# Posso mudar o nome de um atributo ao criar uma tabela a partir de um tipo?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, orientação-a-objetos, oracle

Seguindo o modelo Objeto-Relacional, quero criar as tabelas `or_medico` e `or_atendente` derivadas de `t_funcionario` que eu criei.
Abaixo segue a estrutura do tipo:

```
DROP TYPE t_funcionario FORCE;
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE t_funcionario AS OBJECT (
    cod_func INTEGER,
    nome_func VARCHAR2(50),
    crm_med VARCHAR2(15),
    escala_func VARCHAR2(12)
);
```

E o método criador das tabelas `or_medico` e `or_atendente`

```
DROP TABLE or_medico CASCADE CONSTRAINTS;
CREATE TABLE or_medico OF t_funcionario (
    PRIMARY KEY (cod_func),
    nome_func NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE crm_med,
    escala_func NOT NULL
) OBJECT IDENTIFIER IS SYSTEM GENERATED;

DROP TABLE or_atendente CASCADE CONSTRAINTS;
CREATE TABLE or_atendente OF t_funcionario (
    PRIMARY KEY (cod_func),
    nome_func NOT NULL,
    escala_func NOT NULL
) OBJECT IDENTIFIER IS SYSTEM GENERATED;
```

Fazendo desta maneira, os atributos de ambas as tabelas terminarão com "func", pois derivam de `t_funcionario`.
Teria como mudar o nome dos atributos para que sejam específicos de cada tabela?
Exemplo:

Tabela `or_medico` tem os atributos `cod_med, nome_med, escala_med` e a tabela `or_atendente` tem os atributos `cod_atendente, nome_atendente, escala_atendente`?

Comment: Creio que isto não possa ser feito pois vai prevalecer o atributo do "type" mas a criação da tabela já qualificaria , tire o "func" do tipo primitivo e ficaria or_medico.nome , todavia usar "types" em colunas de banco pode tornar inviável consultas via sql em algumas linguagens em um front-end. Todavia sua pergunta é muito interessante.

Comment: @Motta, fiz a mesma pergunta no StackOverflow em inglês e me disseram o mesmo, que eu não poderia trocar o nome do atributo, pois o nome proveniente do tipo prevaleceria. Vou responder esta pergunta com o link da minha pergunta em inglês.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esta pergunta foi feita no fórum inglês do StackOverflow.

Segue o link para a resposta e as discussões acerca da minha dúvida:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64635677/can-i-change-an-attribute-name-from-a-table-derived-from-a-type?noredirect=1#comment114285705_64635677

Em resumo, o atributo não poderia ser renomeado. Ao tentar utilizar o comando

```
ALTER TABLE ... RENAME COLUMN...
```

retornaria um erro dizendo ser impossível fazer a operação.
O mais indicado a se fazer, seria retirar o sufixo "_func" dos atributos do tipo para generalizá-los e poder aplicar em todas as tabelas derivadas do tipo.